# Proper location to install Android SDK on Mac

Tags: macos, android, installation

What is the best (most proper) location to install the Android SDK on Mac?

I've seen in some posts that somewhere in the Home directory is advantageous.  Some seem to have placed the SDK in the Applications directory.